# After a completed TeX Live installation on Linux: how can I run just the "Create symlinks to standard directories" option?

Tags: texlive, installing, paths

On CentOS 7 I have installed TeX Live 2019 via CLI by running `install-tl` from an ISO image. This install was identified as `x86_64-linux` and finished successfully.

Now, I want to activate the symlinks to the standard directories, so that I do not have to add the TeX directories to my environments variables.

How can I run the installer just with the  "Create symlinks to standard directories" option without re-installing everything?

---

Bonus question: What exactly *does* the "Create symlinks to standard directories" option on the `x86_64-linux` platform do?

Comment: why do you want the symlinks (especially in view of your bonus question) when the texlive maintainers recommend not doing that and just setting the path?

Comment: When you have installed texlive, latex is not in your path yet (programmes are looked up through the ath variable).  You either have to add texlive to the path manually (recommended) or you can have texlive add shortcuts (softlinks) from usr/local/bin (I think) to where latex and friends are. This can be tempting, but is easily forgotten later on especially if you do know what softlinks are. Therefore the recommended method is to manually add texlive to env variables as it is a lot safer.

Comment: Why are softlinks bad. Assume you use softlinks for tl19, tl20 comes along, you attempt to add softlinks again, but they are already there pointing somewhere else and you'll have to remove them manually.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I like symlinks better than even more additions to `PATH`, etc.

Comment: @daleif I do know what symlinks are and they are pretty clearly visible in the filesystem. Therefor I would like to know what symlinks does `install-tl` set via the "Create symlinks" option.

Comment: one simple path addition rather than dozens of version-specific symlinks for every program in texlive. It really is not recommended. But if you want to do it you don't need the installer just a simple shell loop over every file in your texlive bin directory symlink to /usr/local/bin

Comment: It does what I said, make softlinks from either usr/local/bin or usr/bin. In my opinion they are  not a good solution when you forget about them and later on is trying to figure out why your larex no longer works. Testing a path variable is a lot easier that hunting down broken symlinks.

Comment: Use `tlmgr path add`.

Comment: @TeXnician Cool! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @daleif I get your point, but if it is so easy with `tlmgr path add/remove` to manage the symlinks, why not?

Comment: The point of the is that people forget they made them, they got get to remove them when a new tl comes along, plus "Furthermore, any executables added or removed by future updates are not taken care of automatically; this command must be rerun as needed." IMO not worth the trouble when changing the path is so much easier and easier to test afterwards.

Answer (score 8):

*From all the comments to the question and my experience after using them I write up an answer:*

If you want to create symlinks to standard directories *after* the install, do not try to run the install script `install-tl`, but rather use the  native TeX Live manager `tlmgr`.

```
tlmgr path add
```

will attempt to symlink to standard directories. You need the necessary access rights, so normally you will incorporate root via `sudo`.

#### To the bonus question:

Using `tlmgr path add`, what does it do exactly? It will link the *individual* executables, man pages and info files into the standard directories.(*) What are the standard directories `tlmgr` uses? Find out via

```
tlmgr option sys_bin
tlmgr option sys_man
tlmgr option sys_info
```

#### A word of caution

Because `tlmgr` does link many individual files it might be hard to track down broken symlinks later on when you upgrade TeX Live to a newer version. Therefore make sure before upgrading to remove the old symlinks (`tlmgr path remove`) then install the new TeX Live and finally to add the symlinks.

---

(*) The reason why `tlmgr` has to link individual *files* and cannot simply link the  *directory* is that Linux cannot do something like "merge-linking" a directory into another directory.